# How to add number animation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm making a calculator program. It's all working very nicely although very simple.
I wanted to experiment and want to recreate the Cash app animation seen here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/091m1.jpg). I've tried using `NumberFormatter` but I had no luck.

```
var firstNum: String = "";
 
@IBOutlet weak var numOnScreen: UILabel!
//(Answer box) starts out as zero.

@IBAction func numPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //numPressed is linked to all my button 0-9

    firstNum += String(sender.tag);
    numOnScreen.text = firstNum;
}
```

This is currently my code. Numbers show up fine in my app but I really want to add that animation. Could anyone point me to how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate a text change you wrap the setting of the label in a UIView.animation.

```
// Perform animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
    // Update the starting number to the ending number
    startingNumber = endingNumber
}
```

However looking at the Cash app animation, they seem do be going more than just updating a label with an animation.

Here's one way you could implement the animation using a horizontal collection view:

1. Create a collection view with a horizontal flow layout.
2. Each number would be represented by its own cell in the collection view. You could customize the appearance of each cell to match the Cash app design.
3. When the number changes, calculate the difference between the old number and the new number.
4. If the new number is greater than the old number, add new cells to the right of the current cells to represent the additional digits. If the new number is less than the old number, remove cells from the right until the new number is represented.
5. Update the text and appearance of each cell to match the new number.
6. If you added or removed cells, animate the insertion or removal using UICollectionView's insertItems(at:) and deleteItems(at:) methods.
7. Finally, use UICollectionView's scrollToItem(at:animated:) method to scroll to the cell representing the center digit of the new number.

That's how I would do it off the top of my head. But could be better ways. Good luck.